# request body is empty in post method node js server

Tags: node.js, react-native, express

**Login.js - react component.**

I printed the JSON.stringify(credentials) object and it is valid but when i print the req.body in the server it is empty.

```
//sending a post request to the server with the username and password inserted by the user.
async function loginUser(credentials) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(credentials));
  return fetch('http://localhost:8080/login', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(credentials)
  })
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
    })
 };
```

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var cors = require('cors')
 
var app = express()
 
app.use(cors());
// create application/json parser
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json()
 
// create application/x-www-form-urlencoded parser
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })
 
// POST /login gets urlencoded bodies
app.post('/login', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.status(200).send('welcome, ' + req.body.username)
})
```

Comment: why are you parsing data you're sending as "application/json" with the urlencodedParser?      method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(credentials)

Comment: as Joe said - use jsonParser too or instead of urlencodedParser - you just declared it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use a middleware to parse the json body in the post request,
you have not used bodyParser.json() as middleware
below is your updated code
**server.js**

```
var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var cors = require('cors')
 
var app = express()
 
app.use(cors());
// create application/json parser
app.use(bodyParser.json());
// create application/x-www-form-urlencoded parser
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
 
// POST /login gets urlencoded bodies

app.post('/login', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.status(200).send('welcome, ' + req.body.username)
})
```

Comment: @HaniBenGozi glad to be of help :>